# Approximation to a partial sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, harmonic-numbers

Just like $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac1k$$ can be approximated by log(n), is there a similar approximation for the sum $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac1{k^2}$$

Comment: You can apply Euler-Maclaurin to both. The crudest asymptotic for the second is $\pi^2/6+O(1/n)$ but this can be improved.

Comment: Euler-Maclaurin says that $$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{k^2}\sim\frac{\pi^2}6-\frac1n+\frac1{2n^2}-\frac1{6n^3}+\frac1{30n^5}-\frac1{42n^7}+\dots$$

Answer (score 2):

From

$$x-1<\lfloor x\rfloor\le x$$
you draw

$$\frac1{x^d}\le\frac1{\lfloor x\rfloor^d}<\frac1{(x-1)^d}.$$

Then by integration from $2$ to $n+1$,

$$\int_{x=2}^{n+1}\frac{dx}{x^d}\le\sum_{k=2}^n\frac1{k^d}<\int_{x=2}^{n+1}\frac{dx}{(x-1)^d}.$$

So

$$\ln\frac{n+1}2\le\sum_{k=2}^n\frac1{k}<\ln n$$ and

$$\frac12-\frac1{n+1}\le\sum_{k=2}^n\frac1{k^2}<1-\frac1{n}.$$

(Mind the initial index $2$.)

You can get tighter approximations by starting from larger lower bounds and adding the first terms separately.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that, using $\;\psi_1(x)\;$ the [trigamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigamma_function), we have  $\;\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{k^2} = \psi_1(1)-\psi_1(n+1). $ It is known that $\;\psi_1(x) = \frac1x
 + \frac1{2x^2} + \cdots = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{B_k}{x^{k+1}}$ asymptotically using Bernoulli numbers.